# Autoupdate multiple tables based on the user id when there is any update in any of the row

Tags: sqlite

I am using SQLite for my web application. I have a student_id in 4 different tables using as Primary key and Secondary key as well. For example, in the student table, student_id is the primary key. In other tables, I am using student_id as the secondary key. Now I want to add the last updated row in all the tables which have student_id as one of the columns. If there is any change in any of the rows or any of the tables where the student_id exists the last updated row should get an update with the current date in all the tables. I know we have to use triggers for getting the current date if there is any change. Is there any way that I can use one trigger to update all tables base on the student_id with the current date? or any other method?

Comment: Usually, "date updated" refers to one table, not to several tables. For example, if you update "username" in the "users" table, I'd expect "date updated" for that row to be today; I wouldn't expect that change to affect the table "user_addresses". Rethink your problem.

Comment: If that is the case do I need to create a trigger for each table?

Comment: Yes, each table has a simple trigger. Each trigger updates its own table.